# Octave to Matlab: Creating an input file for a wrapper

Tags: matlab, printf, octave

I'm trying to convert a wrapper code of mine from matlab to octave (ah free).  The file "inputc100.txt" is created but is empty everytime I run the code.  This is a simpler version than what I actually have going on but I figure if this works, the others seem to have the same problem.  Perhaps I have a problem formatting my fopen or formatspec or fprintf.  Let me know what you think and thank you so much for looking and helping!

```
gp = 14.0642;
AreaCanp = 42.6;
for ip = 1:21
   Vp(ip) = 100 + 5*(ip-1);
   filenamec = strcat("inputc",num2str(Vp(ip)),".txt");
   fileIDc = fopen(filenamec,'w');
   formatspecc = "%f\n%f";
   fprintf(fileIDc,formatspecc,AreaCanp,gp);
```

Comment: are you closing the file (or at least flushing it) before looking at it?

Comment: A tip for the future: you can format the code to look like code by indenting each line by four spaces or by selecting the text and clicking the `{}` button in the editor's tool bar. It also seems you're missing an `end` at the end of the for loop - is this just a typo, or actually happening in your code?

Comment: Thank you both for the help!  Closing the files worked.  Also, thanks for helping with formatting my code, this is my first post so I need that type of help.  To answer your question darthbith, this is just a section out of my code and I do end my loop later on.  Now I'm having problems with the system command.  I'll research and then put up another question if I can't find the answer, considering that it is a different subject.  Thanks again!